# Python3.5 code identical with different outputs on two machines

Tags: python

I wrote a python program which is using SARIMAX.

```
import warnings
from statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions import ConvergenceWarning
...
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter('ignore', ConvergenceWarning)
        model = SARIMAX(history, order=order, seasonal_order=sorder, trend=trend,
                            enforce_stationarity=False, enforce_invertibility=False)
        model_fit = model.fit(disp=False)
        yhat = model_fit.predict(len(history), len(history))
```

When running on one debian (let's call it debsrv1):
The program runs correctly, without warnings (of course, I defined them to be ignored)
When running on a second debian (let's call it debsrv2):
The program runs correctly, but still displays the warnings.

`/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py:568: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to converge. Check mle_retvals "Check mle_retvals", ConvergenceWarning)`

With pip3 I checked that I have statsmodels (0.11.1) on both machines
Python3 --version returns on both: `python 3.5.3`
Kernel versions are:

```
    debsrv1: Linux 4.9.0-12
    debsrv2: Linux 4.9.0-11
```

But I don't think the kernel is making a difference at this level, is it ?

1. When I run the code locally on my MacOS (statsmodels=0.11.1, python 3.7.7), it's like debsrv1.
2. The DB containing the data to be analyzed by SARIMAX doesn't seem to make a difference.

Any idea what I should check ?
This difference is driving me crazy...
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: It seems nondeterminsitc, so perhaps something with random numbers, some difference in `/dev/random` or something along those lines if the code you call is a wrapper around a C routine which is trying to get an OS-provided source of entropy. Despite the warnings, are the returned solutions similar?

Comment: Sorry for the delay of my answer. I had to check it carefully. Unfortunately, the data changed meanwhile and it changed the computed results. But on the other hand, I completely started from the beginning on the debsrv2 with the python program (but no reinstall), I have now the expected output. I suspect something persistent in some cache...